# Python: convert types in deeply nested dictionary or array

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have written the following helper function to convert ObjectIds (a bson type) to strings.  The function should work for deeply nested dictionaries, arrays, and combinations of the two.

The current function is below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from bson import ObjectId

def clean_dict_helper(d):
    if not d:
        return None
    if isinstance(d, list):  # For those db functions which return list
        if len(d) == 0:
            return []
        return [clean_dict_helper(x) for x in d]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = clean_dict_helper(v)
            d.update({k: v})
        else:
            if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
                v = str(v)
            elif isinstance(v, datetime):
                v = str(v)
            d.update({k: v})
    return d


test_case = {'id': bson.ObjectId("5e126ddf276ab18820e00ddf"), 'arr': [{'value': 4, 'id': bson.ObjectId("5e126ddf276ab18820e00ddf")}]}

result = clean_dict_helper(test_case)

print(result)
>>> {'arr': [{'id': ObjectId('5e126ddf276ab18820e00ddf'), 'value': 4}], 'id': '5e126ddf276ab18820e00ddf'}
```

However it seems to fail for objects inside of arrays inside of Objects.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to iterate through nested iterables and convert types?

Comment: What do you mean by 'arrays inside of Objects', do you actually mean 'arrays inside of dictionaries'? Because there is no clause for `d` being of type `ObjectId` that looks at the insides of `ObjectId`, so that would explain your problem?

Comment: I've edited your question to include an example and a mock class for `ObjectId`, but it appears to be working ok? The output is `{1: {1: 'test1', 2: ['test2', 'test3'], 3: '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 4: [{1: 'test4'}]}, 2: ['test5', 'test6']}` which seems to be what you need?

Comment: I included a breaking test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be easier to reason about if you put the conversion at the start, allow the recursive calls to pass the `ObjectId` and return the converted strings directly with the function rather than trying to convert inside the loops in the function. Then you can just pass the value into the recursion and get the string back.

Something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

def clean_dict_helper(d):
    if isinstance(d, ObjectId) or isinstance(d, datetime):
        return str(d)

    if isinstance(d, list):  # For those db functions which return list
        return [clean_dict_helper(x) for x in d]

    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            d.update({k: clean_dict_helper(v)})

    # return anything else, like a string or number
    return d
```

Calling:

```
clean_dict_helper({
    1: {
        1: ObjectId('5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0'),
        2: [ObjectId('5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0'), ObjectId('5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0')],
        3: datetime(2020, 1, 1),
        4: [{1: ObjectId('5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0')}],
        5: 'test'
    },
    2: [ObjectId('5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0'), ObjectId('5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0')]
})
```

Will then return:

```
{1: {1: '5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0',
  2: ['5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0', '5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0'],
  3: '2020-01-01 00:00:00',
  4: [{1: '5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0'}],
  5: 'test'},
 2: ['5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0', '5e0e83a6d0fbe7238c960ea0']}
```

Also, since you are making a new list with a comprehension, it may make sense to return a new dict rather than mutating the passed in value with something like:

```
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k:clean_dict_helper(v) for k, v in d.items() }
```